# Using Elvis operator in combination with string.Equals

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

I wonder why the following code works in C# 6.0: 
(In this example *data* is a random class containing *val* as a public string)

```
if ("x".Equals(data.val?.ToLower()) { }
```

But the following line isn't:

```
if (data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x")) { }
```

Visual Studio shows me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: how would you handle if (null) ? this what can be returned with data.val?

Comment: I think that because "x".Equals return bool, whereas data.val?..... can return null. And null cannot be converted into bool.

Comment: there's a guy on our team that has called it the `Evlis operator` for months now.  Thought he was the only one.

Comment: I'm guessing because `data.val?` is `bool?`, in other words, it can be null. So you can do `"x".Equals(null)` but with your alternative, the whole thing will evaluate to `null` if `val` is null. So you'd need something like `if(data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x") == true) {}`

Comment: I'd suggest you use `object.Equals(data.val?.ToLower(),"x")` and not worry about what evaluates to what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ("x".Equals(data.val?.ToLower()) { }
```

Will eventually return a boolean because the of [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) call but this:

```
if (data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x")) { }
```

when the expression is evaluated it will return a [`System.Nullable<bool>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) which is different than a `bool` (former is a struct that can be assigned the value `null` while the latter can only be `true` or `false`) the the `if` expects. Also, in C# a `null` value doesn't evaluate to false (according to the C# specification).

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. In short `.Equals(...)` returns a `bool` but `?.` could return a null. This means overall the result of the combination of the two is either a `bool` or `null`, i.e. a `bool?` (nullable bool) ,which is not a valid operand in an `if`

Comment: `Nullable<bool>` is not a reference type, [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0) is a struct, even though one with some unusual properties.

Comment: @svick Thanks for the correction. I never realized that it was a struct since I could give it a null value. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have c# 6.0 to test but this should work

```
if (data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x") ?? false) { }
```

Comment: I agree, the ?. will say don't run the rest.  So returns a null rather than a bool when data.val is null.  The ?? will use false rather than null.

Comment: or `(data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x")).GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: Or even `(data.val?.ToLower()).Equals("x")`.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is evaluating the return value of `Equals` whereas the second statement evaluates to `bool?` which could be null.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the other answers I think it's useful if you write the equivalent code out long hand so you can see what's going on.

The first line is equivalent to:

```
string temp = data.val != null ? data.val.ToLower() : null;
if ("x".Equals(temp)) { }
```

which is perfectly valid and obvious.

The second statement is equivalent to:

```
bool? temp = data.val != null ? data.val.ToLower().Equals("x") : null;
if (temp) { } //error
```

This is perhaps less obvious but the statement `data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x")` will return `null` if `data.val` is `null` otherwise it will return the result of `data.val.ToLower().Equals("x")`. Because the statement can return `null` or `bool` the type of the entire statement is `bool?` but you can't use a `bool?` in an `if` directly.

As others have pointed out, converting the `bool?` to a `bool` will fix your issue. One way of doing that is to use `GetValueOrDefault()`:

```
if (data.val?.ToLower().Equals("x").GetValueOrDefault()) { }
```